# How to set Entity with Foreign key parent to children using with springs, gradle, appengine, jpa, datanucleaus.

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, jpa, gradle, datanucleus

I have two entities: Country (parent) is the hardcoded entity, another one is a Place entity. It is a child entity (states, districts, mandal, villages).

Code below presents the child class.

```
    import javax.jdo.annotations.Index;
    import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

    @Entity
    public class Places {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @Index
        private String place_Name;
        private String placeType;
            @Persistent
        @ManyToOne
        private Country country;

        public Country getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public String getPlace_Name() {
            return place_Name;
        }

        public void setPlace_Name(String place_Name) {
            this.place_Name = place_Name;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setCountry(Country countryByName) {
            this.country = countryByName;
        }

        public String getPlaceType() {
            return placeType;
        }

        public void setPlaceType(String placeType) {
            this.placeType = placeType;
        }

    }
```

Code below is parent entity (code).

```
    package com.geeklabs.rss.domain;

    import javax.jdo.annotations.Index;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Country {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @Index
        private String countryName;
        private String countryCode;

        public String getCountryName() {
            return countryName;
        }
        public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
            this.countryName = countryName;
        }
        public String getCountryCode() {
            return countryCode;
        }
        public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
            this.countryCode = countryCode;
        }
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
```

Below xml file is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="rss" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.geeklabs.rss.domain.Country</class>
         <class>com.geeklabs.rss.domain.Places</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Using classes above I'm trying to assign parent id to child but I got exceptions.
How to assign the foreign key from parent to child using appengine, jpa, datanucleus, spring?

Comment: You mean a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296735/how-to-assiign-entity-with-foreign-key-parent-to-children-using-with-appengine

Comment: Aside from the duplicate case. What exceptions do You receive? Any sample code of the attempt to solve the problem?